# iPhone Analytics

Tags: iphone, google-analytics

With the [recent changes in the SDK agreement](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/06/01/flurry-blamed-for-change-in-iphone-sdk-analytics-terms-of-service/), I am kinda confused if I'm able to put any type of analytics into my app. I don't want to do anything nefarious, just want to see which functionality of my app is getting used the most. I was looking at Google Analytic's mobile sdk to track the different views, just like page views but I have a feeling it is not allowed anymore. Can someone clear up if Google Analytics are still allowed; if not, are any analytics allowed?

Comment: This question here has a detailed breakdown of what is permitted with iPhone analytics from 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083351/iphone-analytics-what-are-the-rules-in-2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of analytics Apple doesn't want (anymore) is stuff like Flurry logging all possible device info, as because of this some (really basic) information leaked on the iPad a couple of weeks before it was announced, which obviously pissed Apple off (Steve Jobs's words). (As detailed in the article you linked to, which I only read after posting this answer.)

Logging other stuff shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually, I believe they're more concerned about third-party data aggregation.  If the statistics are only being sent to you as the developer, you're clear.  Also, the user must opt-in for the analytics, due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Yeah, so that's why I'm wondering if Google Analytics are allowed because they are my analytics but technically they are being sent to Google.